# How to to change mouse cursor on chart.js doughnut graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

When using the Chart.js library, I want to change cursor when hovering the mouse over the doughnut.

I do this :

```
$("#dc_LoadTime").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#dc_LoadTime").css("cursor", "default");
}); 
$("#dc_LoadTime").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#dc_LoadTime").css("cursor", "pointer");
});
```

With this in html page

```
<canvas id="dc_LoadTime"></canvas>
```

But this change cursor when mouse enter or leave canvas not on doughnut chart.
I cannot find a way to do this. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Take a look at http://codepen.io/n33kos/pres/WQMRdL

Comment: which version of chart js are you using? 1.x or 2.x

Comment: @Quince Chart.js v1.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can piggy back on the showTooltip method, like so

```
...
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);

var originalShowTooltip = myDoughnutChart.showTooltip;
myDoughnutChart.showTooltip = function (activeElements) {
    $("#dc_LoadTime").css("cursor", activeElements.length ? "pointer" : "default");
    originalShowTooltip.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: How can we do this for chartjs version 2, on pie and bar charts.?

Answer (score 22):

In chartjs 2.0 < 2.5 I use hover in option section of the chart, like this:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    onHover: function(e) {
      $("#id-of-your-canvas").css("cursor", e[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
    }
  }
}
```

...and here is a complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/su5fgb5h/5/

In version 2.5 onhover callback has changed and we need second parameter to change cursor:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    onHover: function(e, el) {
      $("#id-of-your-canvas").css("cursor", el[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This variation worked for me:
`onHover: function(e, elements) {
          $(e.currentTarget).css("cursor", elements[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
        }`

Comment: Here's a variation in vanilla JS incase it helps anyone:

`onHover: function(e, el) {
   const section = el[0];
   const currentStyle = e.currentTarget.style;
   currentStyle.cursor = section ? 'pointer' : 'normal';
}`

Comment: It works, but the CPU is high when hovering. It would be nice if CSS classes can be specified for those chart elements, since CSS hover effect is  of low CPU consumption.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked

```
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

Add this inside your options like

```
 options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  cutoutPercentage: 75,
  aspectRatio: 1.5,
  // show pointer while hovering
  onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
   },
 };`
```

Comment: For Chart.js need to update to:

`onHover: (event, chartElement) => { event.native.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default'; }`

Comment: For typescript need to cast to HtmlElement:      onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
          (<HTMLElement>event.native.target).style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
        },

Comment: I am using chart3.0 and Paul Keen's answer worked for me